# How Does Resistance Affect EMF Measurements?

Tags: resistance, emf

I have very little electrical engineering knowledge, but am working on a simple Arduino project that detects electromagnetic fields. The original project specifies that three 1M resistors should be used. I've done this and the system works, flashing an LED when the copper wire is brought close to an outlet or (plugged-in) battery. I don't have a schematic, but here's a photo of the project:

[image]

And the sketch:

```
int a = 0;

void setup(){                                                 
  pinMode(A5,INPUT);                                  
  pinMode(9,OUTPUT);                                    
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){                                                           
  int a = analogRead(A5);                                    
  Serial.println(a);                                                 
  if(a > 5){
    analogWrite(9,255);                            
  }
  else {
    analogWrite(9,0);                                          
  }
  delay(10);                                                        
}
```

The original author of the project mentions that increasing the resistance would give better readings, so my question is: How do these 1M resistors affect a system like this in general? From a newbie's perspective, it would seem that resistance would negatively affect readings.

Any very basic explanation(s) on this would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to tell us more about the system than that it uses 3 1-Meg resistors for us to be able to explain how it works. Including a schematic would be the best way to give us the needed information.

Comment: @Vic Post a schematic

Comment: Bring this circuit near the input power cord (AC) or the output (DC) cable of various black-brick power modules. You may be impressed by the variations.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf thank you!... I don't have it in hand at the moment... can you explain what would happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just connecting a resistor between a floating CMOS input and ground, the higher the resistance the higher the sensitivity to electric fields. The resistors determine how much current from the probe is required to switch the input. Something like Vih or Vil divided by R. So more resistance  means less current required and more sensitivity.

However- at some point, leakage from the input will overwhelm the EMF pickup and it will no longer work. Or you may get pickup from unwanted sources and the light will be less selective.

The [chip used in the Arduino](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/SMD/ATMega328.pdf) is rather loosely specified at < 1uA over temperature, so chances are good it won't be anywhere near that high at room temperature but this is not really a great design from an engineering point of view.

[image]